# Error: include_once(): Failed opening './includes/unicode.entities.inc'

Tags: 6, entities

I am working on a D6 site and I have created some fields programatically, and it looked like it worked fine (code below). The fields show up in the database and on the UI screen. However, I found that after adding these field types, when I tried editing data in that content type, it wouldn't save. Looking at the error logs, I saw this:

```
include_once(./includes/unicode.entities.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/usni.utdev.com/htdocs/includes/unicode.inc on line 339.
```

and

```
include_once(): Failed opening './includes/unicode.entities.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /srv/www/usni.utdev.com/htdocs/includes/unicode.inc on line 339.
```

and I can't figure out why I could be causing these errors.

```
function createCckFields($csv) {
  foreach ($csv as $key => $value) {
    list($category, $label, $fieldName, $sampleValue, $fieldType, $cardinality) = $value;
    if ($fieldType == 'text' || $fieldType == 'number_integer' || $fieldType == 'number_float' || $fieldType == 'date') {
      createField($category, $label, $fieldName, $sampleValue, $fieldType, $cardinality);
    }
  }
  return;
}

function createField($category, $label, $fieldName, $sampleValue, $fieldType, $cardinality) {
  if ($fieldType == 'text') {
    $module = 'text';
    $widget_type = 'text_textfield';
    $widget_module = 'text';
    $field_name = 'field_' . $fieldName;
  }
  elseif ($fieldType == 'number_integer' || $fieldType == 'number_float') {
    $module = 'number';
    $widget_type = 'number';
    $widget_module = 'number';
    $field_name = 'field_' . $fieldName;
  }
  elseif ($fieldType == 'date') {
    $module = 'date';
    $widget_type = 'date_popup'; //options: date_popup, date_text
    $widget_module = 'date';
    $field_name = 'field_' . $fieldName;
  }
  elseif ($fieldType == 'N/A' && $fieldName == 'RelatedProducts') { //@TODO TAKE OUT HARDCODED FIELDNAME, NEED TO DEAL WITH REVIEW QUOTES TOO
    //this is for fields which have a cardinality of  $field_name,
    'type_name' => 'product',
    'display_settings' => array(
      'label' => array(
        'format' => 'hidden',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => array(
        'format' => 'hidden',
        'exclude' => 1,
      ),
      'full' => array(
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'widget_active' => 1,
    'type' => $fieldType, //options: text, number_integer, date
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => $cardinality,
    'db_storage' => 1,  //not sure what this does
    'module' => $module, //options: text, number, date
    'active' => 1,
    'locked' => 0,
    'widget' => array(
      'label' => $label,
      /*'default_value' => array(
        0 => array(
          'value' => $sampleValue,
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][' . $field_name . '][0][value',
        ),
      ),*/
      'weight' => 2,
      'description' => 'ie: ' . $sampleValue,
      'type' => $widget_type, //options: text_textfield, optionwidgets_onoff
      'module' => $widget_module, //options: text, optionwidgets
    ),
  );

  if ($fieldType == 'date') {
    $field['granularity'] = array(
      'year' => 'year',
      'month' => 'month',
      'day' => 'day',
    );
    $field['timezone_db'] = '';
    $field['tz_handling'] = 'none'; //this is set to none, since we are not tracking hour and minute in the granularity
    $field['todate'] = '';
    $field['repeat'] = 0;
    $field['repeat_collapsed'] = '';
    $field['default_format'] = 'medium';
    $field['widget']['default_value_code'] = "";
    $field['widget']['default_value2'] = 'blank';
    $field['widget']['default_value_code2'] = '';
    $field['widget']['input_format'] = 'Y-m-d:i:s';
    $field['widget']['input_format_custom'] = 'Ymd'; //the format set for the date fields in onix is YYYYMMDD
    $field['widget']['increment'] = 1;
    $field['widget']['text_parts'] = array();
    $field['widget']['year_range'] = '-3:+3';
    $field['widget']['label_position'] = 'above';
  }
  elseif ($fieldType == 'nodereference') {
    $node_types = node_get_types('names');
    foreach($node_types as $type=>$value) {
      $node_types[$type] = 0;
    }
    $node_types['product'] = 'product';
    $field['referenceable_types'] = $node_types;
    $field['advanced_view'] = '--';
    $field['advanced_view_args'] = '';
    $field['widget']['autocomplete_match'] = 'contains';
    //$field['widget']['size'] = 60;
    //field['widget']['default_value'] = null;
  }
  module_load_include('inc', 'content', 'includes/content.crud');
  if (content_fields($field, 'product')) {
    //content_field_instance_update($field);
    drupal_set_message('Did not create field_' . $fieldName . ' of type ' . $fieldType);
  }
  else {
    content_field_instance_create($field);
    drupal_set_message('Created  field_' . $fieldName . ' of type ' . $fieldType);
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing those errors, but that was not the issue. I found out that the issue was that I had been creating fields with field names longer than 32 characters, which Drupal doesn't like. I added a 32 character limit to the names, and everything worked fine.